# Multi step Blazor form attempts to get submitted on click of an ordinary button

Tags: .net, validation, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-editform

I am creating a multi-step Blazor form using the wizard component logic as per [this](https://sinclairinat0r.com/2019/12/08/creating-a-simple-wizard-component-in-blazor) article. Project is .NET 5.0 Blazor Client (Hosted). There is a parent `Wizard` component which has `WizardStep` children components.

I am trying to create a simple two-step form. Step no. 1 contains an input date control and Step no. 2/final step contains a text area control.

[image: Here is]

It can be seen in the above image that the *Next* button in step 1 of my form has a type "button". When this *Next* button is clicked, the current `WizardStep` component gets replaced and the next/final `WizardStep` component gets rendered. This final `WizardStep` contains the text area control and the *Next* button gets replaced with the *Submit* button. However, it can be seen that the final step shows Validation errors. These validation errors come without clicking the *Submit* button in the final step.

[image]

I have debugged the app and can tell that upon clicking the *Next* button in step 1, the form attempts to get submitted and that is why the validation errors are appearing. This should not happen as the type of *Next* button is "button".

Why is this issue happening? The form should only submit after clicking a button of type "submit", and this button appears in the final step of the wizard.

One more thing to be noted in the above image is that the *Submit* button in the next/final step of the form appears as if it is being clicked. Why?

**Form**

```
 <EditForm Model="model" OnValidSubmit="SubmitValidForm">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
    
        <Wizard Id="TestForm">
            <WizardStep Name="First Step">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date:</label>
                    <div>
                        <InputDate @bind-Value="@model.Date" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.Date)" />
                </div>
            </WizardStep>
            <WizardStep Name="Final Step">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Details:</label>
                    <div>
                        <InputTextArea @bind-Value="@model.Entry" class="form-control" rows="8" />
                    </div>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.Entry)" />
                </div>
            </WizardStep>
        </Wizard>
    
    </EditForm>
```

**Wizard**

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <div id="@Id">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    Step @(ActiveStepIx + 1) of @Steps.Count
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                @ChildContent
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col p-0">
                            <button class="col-6 btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-left" type="button"
                                    disabled="@(ActiveStepIx == 0)" @onclick="GoBack">
                                Previous
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col p-0">
                            <button class="col-6 btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right"
                                    type="@(IsLastStep ? "submit" : "button")" @onclick="GoNext">
                                @(IsLastStep ? "Submit" : "Next")
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</CascadingValue>

@code
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List of <see cref="WizardStep"/> added to the Wizard
    /// </summary>
    protected internal List<WizardStep> Steps = new List<WizardStep>();

    /// <summary>
    /// The control Id
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The ChildContent container for <see cref="WizardStep"/>
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Active <see cref="WizardStep"/>
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public WizardStep ActiveStep { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Index number of the <see cref="ActiveStep"/>
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public int ActiveStepIx { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the Wizard is in the last step
    /// </summary>

    public bool IsLastStep { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the <see cref="ActiveStep"/> to the previous Index
    /// </summary>

    protected internal void GoBack()
    {
        if (ActiveStepIx > 0)
            SetActive(Steps[ActiveStepIx - 1]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the <see cref="ActiveStep"/> to the next Index
    /// </summary>
    protected internal void GoNext()
    {
        if (ActiveStepIx < Steps.Count - 1)
            SetActive(Steps[(Steps.IndexOf(ActiveStep) + 1)]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the <see cref="ActiveStep"/> the Sets the passed in <see cref="WizardStep"/> instance as the
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="step">The WizardStep</param>

    protected internal void SetActive(WizardStep step)
    {
        ActiveStep = step ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(step));

        ActiveStepIx = StepsIndex(step);
        if (ActiveStepIx == Steps.Count - 1)
            IsLastStep = true;
        else
            IsLastStep = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the index of the current <see cref="WizardStep"/> in the Step List
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="step">The WizardStep</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int StepsIndex(WizardStep step) => StepsIndexInternal(step);

    protected int StepsIndexInternal(WizardStep step)
    {
        if (step == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(step));

        return Steps.IndexOf(step);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a <see cref="WizardStep"/> to the WizardSteps list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="step"></param>
    protected internal void AddStep(WizardStep step)
    {
        Steps.Add(step);
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            SetActive(Steps[0]);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**WizardStep**

```
@if (Parent.ActiveStep == this)
{
    <div id="step-@(Parent.StepsIndex(this) + 1)">
        @ChildContent
    </div>
}

@code {
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Wizard"/> container
    /// </summary>
    [CascadingParameter]
    protected internal Wizard Parent { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Child Content of the current <see cref="WizardStep"/>
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Name of the step
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Parent.AddStep(this);
    }
}
```

The `Wizard` and `WizardStep` logic can be read about in [this](https://sinclairinat0r.com/2019/12/08/creating-a-simple-wizard-component-in-blazor) article. The basic issue, as per my understanding, is that the form is being submitted with the click of an ordinary "button", which should not happen.

Comment: In more complex scenarios, I prefer to manually control submission similar to this: https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/forms-and-validation/how-do-you-manually-trigger-the-form-validation-in-blazor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try using this setting on next button:

```
<button @onclick:stopPropagation=true/>
```

Events in HTML DOM (document object model) bubbles up, in this case, the button click event was bubbling up and reaching to submit button and causing a Submit, if we do not want an event to bubble up to parent DOM then we should suppress them.

Comment: Thank you. This has solved the issue. Can you please let me know why this issue was being caused? How does this statement fix it?

Comment: Events in html DOM (document object model) bubbles up, in this case button click event was bubbling up and reaching to submit button and causing a Submit, if we do not want any event to bubble up to parent  DOM then we should suppress them

Comment: Ok. I will read more about event bubbles. After adding the above setting, the *Next* button code looks like this: 

`<button class="col-6 btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right"  type="button"
  @onclick:stopPropagation=true @onclick="GoNext">Next</button>`

I am using the `@onclick` event call twice. It is working fine.

Comment: Yes, that's completely fine, at one occasion we are handling click event and calling GoNext method, and on second occasion not allowing click event to bubble up by using  @onclick:stopPropagation=true

Comment: Nice. Can you please recommend to me a source where I can read more about such events? I am new to Blazor and get stuck in some problem every now and then. Some course or content that can help me in understanding such concepts better?

Comment: Junaid, its not specific to Blazor but solely related to HTML & JavaScript, this issue can happen anywhere wherever we use html and JavaScript, you can google some good articles on entry level JavaScript, will let you know if I find one.

Comment: `<button type='button' .. />` would also work.